# How to set 80 columns in LispWorks?

Tags: common-lisp, lispworks

I'm very new with Common Lisp and LispWorks so please describe all the steps.
I want to set 80 columns, how can I do?
I'm using LispWorks Personal.

I have found this command, but I don't know how to use it... where have I to write those two commands?

```
Turn on auto-fill-mode:

(setf fill-column 80)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

Thank you.

Comment: Lispworks has a latex mode? I has a function ADD-HOOK? Never heard of that. Are you sure you are doing something useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for you to set the lini width to the canonical 80 columns in Lispworks Personal is the run the command "Auto Fill Mode".

You hit M-x in any buffer and, at the "Extended Command:" prompt you just type "Auto Fill Mode" (autocompletion via Tab works).

In Lispworks Personal edition you cannot use an init file, so it is pointless to try to put any commands in the ~/.lispworks file.

The commands you show in you post, appear to be Emacs ones, in ELisp. They will not function in Lispworks, which uses an Emacs, but different from the GNU based one.  As Rainer said, LW does not have a LaTeX mode.
Cheers
MA